# How to add item in spinner?in which first item is added statically and other dynamically?

Tags: android, spinner

I want to add first item Static and other item by array in spinner. how can i achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

you can override getCount and getItem method of adapter.

```
public int getCount()
{
  return arr.length+1;
}

public Object getItem(int position)
{
   if(position==0)
      return "Select";
   else
      return arr[position-1];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use this way. hope it may help you.

i create one array list global in my Activity.

like :

```
public static ArrayList<String> Party_list = new ArrayList<String>();
```

in oncreate put method like below:

```
public void distic_party_name() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        main_genral_class.Party_list.add("Party");
        sqldb = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = sqldb.query(true, TB_NAME2, new String[] { TB2_fld0 },
                TB2_fld23 + " = 'no'", null, null, null, null, null);

        if (cursor != null) {
            if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                do {

                    String a = cursor
                            .getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(TB2_fld0));

                    main_genral_class.Party_list.add("" + a);

                } while (cursor.moveToNext());
            }
        }
        cursor.close();
    }
```

i added static data first line in method.

```
Party_list.add("Party");
```

Comment: I think He hasn't mentioned about to add data from database.

Comment: this is just idea. how to use static and dynamic data in array.